# Android classes not found after importing Maven project

Tags: java, android, maven

Using Android Studio 1.2, I just imported a Maven project. All seemed to be fine until I went to build, which resulted in the following classes not being found:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

Any ideas on what would be going on here? Sorry I don't have more info right now, but if there is something specific that may help then please ask.

Thank you.

Comment: Clean and build your project :)

Comment: can you share your 'build.gradle' and the 'error log'?

Comment: I've tried rebuilding with no success. Also, no build.gradle file as I am using maven.